# C++: How to correctly write in a .csv file

Tags: c++, csv, c++-cli

I have following data in a text file

> 04EC3AC705EA3AC8042C3BC7051A3AC8043C3AD7054A3AE8

I want to put this data into a .csv file in a **single column** as follows.

```
04EC,3AC7
05EA,3AC8
042C,3BC7
051A,3AC8
043C,3AD7
054A,3AE8
```

What I tried so far is:

```
fp=fopen("D:/pattern.csv", "a+")
 Then I read the original values from the text file in a buffer
fwrite(buffer, 48,1,fp);
```

But again I get all values in a single cell in the csv sheet.

Please tell me a better way to achieve this.  I developed this code in MSVS 2010 win32 and I will be using this code in another application written in C++/CLI Windows form application.

Thanks

Comment: I wander if using `"ä+"` instead of `"a+"` in `fopen()` is valid.

Comment: @MikeCAT That was a typo

Comment: Writing to CSV file is much easier than writing to XLS file. Do you have to use XLS file?

Comment: @gpuguy What's `buffer` and how is the data formatted there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ buffer is char array

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes , you are right

Comment: @MikeCAT How do we proceed if CSV work for my application? . I am changing the question accordingly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to use a .csv file and not excel file. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @gpuguy First take all of the substrings into a `vector<string>` and then write them out pairwise in a loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you post this as an example?

Comment: @gpuguy I'm afraid no. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Just check the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/). And rather use `std::ofstream` BTW, it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand, your input file contains only one line with a single string. And you want to convert it to pairs of 4 char ?

What about a more 'C++' way like this ?

```
std::string input_file_name = "input.txt";
std::string output_file_name = "output.csv";

std::string line;
std::ifstream input_file(input_file_name.c_str());
input_file >> line;

std::ofstream output_file(output_file_name.c_str());
for(unsigned long int i = 0; i + 7 < line.length(); i += 8)
  output_file << line.substr(i, 4) << "," << line.substr(i + 4, 4) << std::endl;
```